# Facebook Marketing API, AdCreative, update "View Tags"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Is there a way to update (or setup when creating) `View Tags` field for an AdCreative via API?
[image: tracking options screenshot]